# Create ForeignKey(imbedded) objects

Tags: django

Here my models:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    number = models.IntegerField()

class BoxContent(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit)

class Box(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    myitems = models.ManyToManyField(BoxContent, blank=True, null=True)
```

and my Views:

```
box = Box.objects.create(number="test")
box.myitems.add(BoxContent.objects.create(fruit=...)
```

but how to create `Fruit` object?

Answer (score 0):

Fruit creation shouldn't be any different from other model object creations

```
fruit = Fruit.objects.create(name='orange', number=1)
box_content = BoxContent.objects.create(fruit=fruit)
box = Box.objects.create(number="test")
box.myitems.add(box_content)
```